# VS2015 C++ DLL and such with Add Reference

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015

I have three VS2015 projects  (DLL, C++ App & C# App)

I created the DLL and targeted v4.5 Framework
I created the C++ Application and targeted the v4.5 framwork and then was able to add reference without an issue.
I create the C# Application and targeted the v4.5 framework and then the Add reference fails with check your assembly or COM message.

Both applications have the DLL project added to the solution.

What else can I check as to why my C# process can't add reference?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Bit of flaw in the New Project dialog for C++ projects, the .NET Framework selection does not actually get used.  If you want a C# program to directly use a C++ DLL then you must create a COM server or use the Visual-C++ > CLR > Class Library project.  A regular DLL requires using pinvoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around it using PInvode and the C# project didn't need to Add Reference afterall.  I had to manually edit out the Precompiled header stuff to force that NotUsing.  Thanks for the quick response... just had a quick turn around for my boss.  Handed a working Cipher DLL for use with both C++ and C# in his project.